# Relative speed of definite integration and indefinite integration with substitution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax

Suppose some complicated integrable function $f[x]$ (possibly depending on parameters). One can perform definite integration over $x$ inside the domain $[a,b]$ by using construction

```
g[x_] = Integrate[f[x],x];
Answer = g[b]-g[a]
```

or by using construction

```
Answer = Integrate[f[x],{x,a,b}]
```

It turns out that often the first construction gives the answer more faster than the second one. What is the reason for this?

Comment: I suspect the answer is in the blog post I linked on your other question. Likely, behind the scenes, it constructs an antiderivative, and then: "So how does Mathematica get its answer? It has to be more careful. Sometimes it works by detecting discontinuities in the antiderivative, and then breaking up the integration region into parts, and carefully taking directional limits at the discontinuity points..."  But I don't actually know, so maybe someone will come along with the answer.

Comment: As mentioned, *Mathematica* has to be a bit more careful (branch cuts, singularities, etc.) in definite integration. If you know what you're doing, and you're sure that your integrand is continuous within the integration interval, feel free to use the first snippet.

Comment: The alternative to waiting for the second one to finish is that you do the analysis of poles and cuts yourself. But then, you may have to do that anyway for writing a paper...